# Selenium IDE - fakepath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I need to upload a file through "browse" button , but when I chose a file , it seems as "fakepath" . My test faces an issue. How can I deal with it?

Comment: Still are you working with Selenium-IDE? Which browser supports IDE?

Comment: @BharatMane FireFox and Chrome (including current versions).

Comment: yes I am. Chrome.